# Django: mixed translations issue

Tags: django, internationalization, http-headers

I configured my application to support 2 languages: english and italian.
In my settings.py I specified i18n-related stuff as following:

```
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', 'ENGLISH'),
    ('it', 'ITALIAN'),
)
```

then I created a "locale" folder for each application and used the following commands to generate .po/.mo files:

```
django-admin.py makemessages -l en --no-location --no-obsolete
django-admin.py makemessages -l it --no-location --no-obsolete
django-admin.py compilemessages
```

All works fine, but I have a template where the two translations get mixed up (ie: part of the texts are in italian and other in english). I think that the problem is related to how my browser (Chrome) sends language headers (currently: `Accept-Language: it,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6`).
Other browser on my machine like Firefox are sending: `Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5`
Ok, this may be a personal problem related to a "strange browser configuration", but is not acceptable to have such result... how can I avoid this issue and have a coherent translation?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that there is some content with origin from DB and thus not provided with translations?

On the other hand it may be the problem in rendering multiline fields in your .po files or .html files (make sure everything is {% trans ... %} wrapped.

Lastly if in Chrome you ask for translation in English when you are in the Italian site, does it provide you with all English content and vice verso?